# Getting kernel error while trying to open Jupyter notebook or Spyder

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, kernel

While opening Jupyter notebook or Spyder, I am continuously getting 'kernel error' notification.

Tried to reinstall anaconda3, ipython, kernel but the issue stays. I had downloaded Python 3.7 in Windows 10 system.

I am getting the below error in log.

"> Traceback (most recent call last): File
"> "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipytho"nconsole.py",

> line 1572, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
>   kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle) File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py",
>   line 240, in start_kernel self.write_connection_file() File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
>   line 476, in write_connection_file kernel_name=self.kernel_name File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py",
>   line 141, in write_connection_file with secure_write(fname) as f: File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line
>   112, in **enter** return next(self.gen) File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py",
>   line 404, in secure_write win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname) File
>   "C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py",
>   line 359, in win32_restrict_file_to_user import win32api ImportError:
>   DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

Comment: `win32_restrict_file_to_user import win32api ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.` --> seems your problem is Windows. Also try to run it as admin

Comment: Thanks Leos313. The problem has been resolved by downgrading the pywin32.Required to run this- pip install --upgrade pywin32==224

Answer (score 6):

Its basically system compatible issues with python/Jupiter.

Please locate the file `pywin32_postinstall.py` in your python installed path

Example

```
C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts>
```

And navigate to the path and run the file/command  `pywin32_postinstall.py -install`

Answer (score 3):

`pip install pywin32 -U`

Should do the trick

Comment: `-U` helped in work with conda env installed in custom directory. After 1 month of hit and trial...

Answer (score 1):

After longer looking here and there I found this question but none of answers helped me, after all I have noticed the correct solution in comments, so I add it here as answer for future readers that might not check the comments at first like me.

Downgrading pywin32 to version 224 is the way:

```
pip install --upgrade pywin32==224
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue for several days. I was using Jupyter notebook. Installation was Anaconda and Python version was 3.8.

I did the following to finally get it fixed:

1.I copied the 2 win32 dlls from
`C:\Users\YourUser\anaconda3\pkgs\pywin32-227-py38he774522_1\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32`  <path where anaconda is installed

to
`c:\windows\system32`
per advice in this thread (not sure if this was necessary, as this didn't immediately fix the problem. The next 2 steps are what fixed it for me.

2.per this https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4980#issuecomment-663885620  (he says pip uninstall pywin32 and conda install it.)

I ran a terminal cmd prompt from anaconda navigator (have to be running as admin)  to
`pip uninstall pywin32`

I had to look up how to run pip install and uninstall from anaconda installation. Googled how to use pip with anaconda and the following instructions came up which worked great.

- Open Anaconda. Select Environments in the left hand pane below home.
  Just to the right of where you selected and below the "search
  environments" bar, you should see base(root). Click on it. A triangle
  pointing right should appear, click on it an select "open terminal"
  Use the regular pip install command here.

3.ran conda install from anaconda prompt as admin per this website, https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pywin32 :
`conda install -c anaconda pywin32`

Finally Jupyter Kernel stopped crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the win32api file from the ..//site-packages/win32 folder to the ..//site-packages//jupyter_core folder finally did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this to resolve the issue when a kernel is dead.

`pip install --upgrade pywin32==224` (downgrade the pywin32 from 225 to 224)
or
`pip install --upgrade pywin32==224 --user`

If the above still not work and one prompt appears that pythoncom37.dll should not be the path 'C:\Windows\System32' then remove the 'pythoncom37.dll' from 'C:\Windows\System32'.

Answer (score 0):

I started all over:

- I uninstalled notebook.
- I uninstalled python 3.7.9.
- I then reinstalled python 3.8.4 and.
- reinstalled notebook.

Problem solved!

Comment: `pip install --upgrade jupyter_client` via https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/5014#issuecomment-547762322

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in a miniconda on conda environment. You could just install pywin32 using conda instead of pip.

This solved my problem

conda install pywin32

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new environment with python 3.9 or 3.10. This is an environment related issue.