# Kernel error in Jupyter Notebook; unable to install pywin32-postinstall

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I know that people already did topics on similar question and most of them I've already read, but it still didn't solve my problem, so I hope I could find help here.

I'm new to Python and faced with the same problem of Kernel Error in Jupyter Notebook as it was described here:
[Getting kernel error while trying to open Jupyter notebook or Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341160/getting-kernel-error-while-trying-to-open-jupyter-notebook-or-spyder)

I use Miniconda and python 3.9 already installed.
I've tried to implement advice that in that topic, but after I installed pywin32, I've faced with the problem of installing pywin32_postinstall. Every time I try to run it, in the output printed "PackagesNotFoundError: The following package are not available from current channels"
(Sorry, but I'm unable to provide complete piece of code, case I don't know how to cope from Anaconda PowerShell Promt)

I would be so much thankful if anyone could help me with this issue!