# An error ocurred while starting the kernel in spyder

Tags: python, azure, installation, anaconda, spyder

I ran these two pip codes: `--user pip install azureml-explain-model` and `--user pip install azureml-interpret` in the anaconda command prompt and then this error showed up.
The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 1568, in create_kernel_manager_and_kernel_client
kernel_manager.start_kernel(stderr=stderr_handle,
File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 337, in start_kernel
kernel_cmd, kw = self.pre_start_kernel(**kw)
File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 286, in pre_start_kernel
self.write_connection_file()
File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 466, in write_connection_file
self.connection_file, cfg = write_connection_file(self.connection_file,
File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 136, in write_connection_file
with secure_write(fname) as f:
File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 113, in __enter__
return next(self.gen)
File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 461, in secure_write
win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
File "C:\Users\risha\anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\jupyter_core\paths.py", line 387, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
import win32api
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Help me, please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve this `import win32api ImportError: DLL load failed while importing win32api: The specified procedure could not be found.` error, try following ways:

1. If you are using `Python 3.8`, upgrade `pywin32` using `pip`:

```
pip install --upgrade pywin32==225
```

**OR**

2. Install `pywin32` using `conda`:

```
conda install pywin32
```

Afer installing `pywin32`, make sure to run post installation script at specific Python location:

```
python [environment path]/Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install
```

References: [Getting kernel error while trying to open Jupyter notebook or Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58341160/getting-kernel-error-while-trying-to-open-jupyter-notebook-or-spyder), [How to fix "ImportError: DLL load failed" while importing win32api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58612306/how-to-fix-importerror-dll-load-failed-while-importing-win32api) and [Kernel error win32api](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4980)